# Enlarge the Defined Box in Dojo

Tags: html, css, dojo

I want to increase the height and width of the inner box (Arrow is pointing) of the Overlay in the below image using DOJO.

Below is my code. Please let me know where I suppose to add in order to increase the height and width.[image]

```
<div class="xx-common-overlay" id="overlay-0">
    <div class="xx-head">
        <p><a class="xx-common-overlay-close" href="#close">Close [x]</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="xx-body">
    <div class="xx-main">
        <a id="xx-access Accessibility anchor" class="xx-access"></a>
        <div class="xx-title">
            <h2 style="font-size: 1.6em;">Please select </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="xx-container">
            <h2 style="padding-top: 10px;">Items:</h2>
            <div class="xx-container-body">
                <p style="padding-top: 5px;">
                    <select multiple="true" id="ItemsOverlay1" name="Items0" style="min-width: 600px;" dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect" onchange="setValues(this, 'fromItems','');"></select>
                </p>
                <input class="xx-btn-arrow-pri" value="OK" type="button" onclick="xxweb.overlay.hide('overlay-0',this); setValues('null', 'fromPlatform','ok');return false;"/>
                <input style="margin-left: 10px;" class="xx-btn-arrow-pri" value="Cancel" type="button" onclick="xxweb.overlay.hide('overlay-0',this); setValues('null', 'fromItems','cancel');return false;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You provided code can not be parse, but you could try the following:

find `dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect"`

change to `style="min-width: 600px;" dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect"`

Comment: Hi Allen, I have added here but size is not getting varied..Plz, check whether I have added in right!!..place. <select multiple="true" id="platformsOverlay1" style="min-width: 600px;" name="platforms0" dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect" onchange="setValues(this, 'fromPlatform','');">
           
      </select>

Comment: Please provide the full page html code for debug. Base on I provided code, it is work. Actually you paste as a correct location.